# How to import IEEE template into Overleaf?

Tags: document-classes

I'm trying to import a template from IEEE (https://2021apsursi.org/Papers.asp) into Overleaf but I keep getting an error message.
Here is the picture:
[image]

and the error log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.10) 3 MAY 2021 18:03
entering extended mode
\write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**"ursi2021_template 1.tex"
(/compile/ursi2021_template 1.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17>

! LaTeX Error: File `ursi2021.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.2 \special
{papersize=8.5in,11in}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
24 strings out of 480906
532 string characters out of 5908280
242476 words of memory out of 5000000
15718 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
535088 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
20i,0n,25p,81b,10s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your file needs to be named as `ursi2021.cls`, right now it has been named as `ursi2021.cls.text`.
Changing that should fix the current error.

Comment: You are right! Thank you!